# is there a better solution for matplotlib AttributeError: module 'backend_interagg' has no attribute 'FigureCanvas'. Did you mean: 'FigureCanvasAgg'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, pycharm

I just started working on a Windows 11, just downloaded pycharm 2022.2.2 (Professional Edition) Build #PY-222.4167.33, installed cv2 via `pip install opencv-contrib-python` and matplotlib 3.6.0 via `pip install -U matplotlib`. And Using python 3.10 as interpreter

TL;DR:
I got AttributeError on backend of matplotlib used to render on embed PyCharm's tool and I fixed it by modifying the library of matplotlib, is there a better solution?

I need to work with looping plots, so notabling i need the plots to work with the option of pycharm "Show plots in tool window" ticked so i dont get lots of windows spaming.
I got this attribute error by this simple code!:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread('IMG_9249.PNG', 0)

plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

that thorws me the error (just putting the relevan last lines)

```
  File "C:\Users\CamiloB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 266, in switch_backend
    canvas_class = backend_mod.FigureCanvas
AttributeError: module 'backend_interagg' has no attribute 'FigureCanvas'. Did you mean: 'FigureCanvasAgg'?
```

so after some findings I figureted out that ticking the "Show plots in tool window" changes the backend of matplot to `module://backend_interagg` and thus using `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` might fix the error (same as unticking "Show plots in tool window"), it brings the plot to a separated window, that is undesired
(I simple did:)

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print(matplotlib.get_backend())  # here prints "module://backend_interagg" on pycharm with "Show plots in tool window" ticked
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
print(matplotlib.get_backend())  # here prints "TkAgg"

img = cv2.imread('IMG_9249.PNG', 0)

plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

so I decide go to where the error raised on the library and edit it with try/except, the error says matplotlib\pyplot.py on line 266 and i changed the lines from:

```py
    canvas_class = backend_mod.FigureCanvas
```

to:

```py
    try:
        canvas_class = backend_mod.FigureCanvas
    except AttributeError:
        canvas_class = backend_mod.FigureCanvasAgg
```

then excuting throws same error on line 185 on same file, so modifiying from:

```py
def _get_required_interactive_framework(backend_mod):
    if not hasattr(backend_mod.FigureCanvas, "required_interactive_framework"):
        _api.warn_deprecated(
            "3.6", name="Support for FigureCanvases without a "
            "required_interactive_framework attribute")
        return None
    # Inline this once the deprecation elapses.
    return backend_mod.FigureCanvas.required_interactive_framework
```

to

```py
def _get_required_interactive_framework(backend_mod):
    try:
        aux_backend = backend_mod.FigureCanvas
    except AttributeError:
        aux_backend = backend_mod.FigureCanvasAgg
    if not hasattr(aux_backend, "required_interactive_framework"):
        _api.warn_deprecated(
            "3.6", name="Support for FigureCanvases without a "
            "required_interactive_framework attribute")
        return None
    # Inline this once the deprecation elapses.
    return aux_backend.required_interactive_framework
```

These changes on the library of matplotlib fixes my problem and the images plots correctly on the embed tool of pycharm only that I got these warnings:

```
C:\Users\CamiloB\Desktop\Gertyid2\codigo python\detectblurry.py:16: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Support for FigureCanvases without a required_interactive_framework attribute was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.6 and will be removed two minor releases later.
  plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
C:\Users\CamiloB\Desktop\Gertyid2\codigo python\detectblurry.py:17: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Support for FigureCanvases without a required_interactive_framework attribute was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.6 and will be removed two minor releases later.
  plt.show()
```

but by the time it doesn't make any trouble

Thus i fixed the problem, it doesnt feel right to modify the library, someone would know a better solution?.

I dont know who to blame, matplotlib?, pycharm?, windows 11? or did I just installed something wrong?